# Meteor.js on windows, how to connect to existing database

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using meteor.js for one of my project, I have mongoDB already(existing from previous application) where am i supposed to change the setting to connect to existing database.
Let me say, I am running on windows.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean a deployed project? Use the [MONGO_URL](http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying) environmental variable before you run your app.

```
set MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor
```

I'm not too sure about windows, but if you have trouble with this copy your mongo database into the *.meteor/local/db* folder of your app

Comment: Not Deploy, I would want to use existing mongo database with meteor.

Comment: Does the second way work? I'm not 100% sure about windows. It might also be better because then you would have 2 mongodb's running at the same time with one doing nothing

Comment: Not Deploy, I would want to use existing mongo database with meteor.
I tried this, set MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3002/test_metoer
after this I started meteor...now the whole application is crashing..
What file, am i supposed to copy to the

Comment: The default database would already be running at port 3002 so your meteor app would crash as something is using the port. How are you running mongodb is it from another meteor instance or a seperate mongodb instance? In your mongodb database that you would like to use at where you specified your data folder, you could copy the contents over to `.meteor/local/db` to use them in your new meteor app.